# A palavra «Venterécia» existe?

Tags: significado, palavra-para-ideia, português-brasileiro

Ouvi a palavra «Venterécia» entre imigrantes japoneses, no Brasil.

Pode ser uma parte de peixe, ou relacionada com o delicioso peixe [pirarucu (Wikupédia)](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pirarucu).
Mas o que significa, exatamente?

Não consegui encontrar a palavra em nenhuma fonte, nem sequer pesquisando no Google.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A palavra que procuras é [*ventrecha* (Priberam)](http://www.priberam.pt/dlpo/ventrecha) ou [*ventrisca* (Periberam):](http://www.priberam.pt/dlpo/ventrisca)

> 1. Posta de peixe imediata à cabeça.
> 2. [Antigo]  Divisão interior. = COMPARTIMENTO